# number of points with integer coordinates of a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^3$ through the origin

Tags: combinatorics

Take the line segment between $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{Z}$. What's the shortest way to count the number of points in this line segment that have integer coordinates?

I was wondering how to do this as I was solving a problem that hinged on showing no such points are in some line segment in three dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is invariant under translations and reflections, so without loss of generality you can assume $a=b=c=0$ and $d,e,f \ge 0$. If such an $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ satisfies $\alpha d, \alpha e, \alpha f \in \mathbb Q$, then of course $\alpha$ is rational, so write $\alpha = p/q$. Then $pd/q, pe/q,pf/q \in \mathbb Z$, hence assuming $(p,q) = 1$, this means $q | (d,e,f)$. Since the smallest positive (i.e. $> 0$) $\alpha$ for which this works is clearly $\alpha = \frac 1{(d,e,f)}$ and that solutions are all equidistant, you see that there are precisely $(d,e,f) + 1$ solutions.

Now it suffices to see how this solution behaves under translation. $d$, $e$ and $f$ are the distances between the coordinates of our two points, and these distances are invariant under translations and reflections, so given $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb Z$, the number of solutions is $(|a-d|,|b-e|,|c-f|) + 1$. The "fastest algorithm" is therefore a greatest-common-divisor algorithm.

Hope that helps,